# JQuery библиотека не подключается

Tags: html, jquery, css

Мне необходимо чтобы текст над картинкой появлялся только при наведении, что в этом случае я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как указано в [справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> Если у `<script>` присутствует атрибут `src`, то код внутри - игнорируется.

То же самое в [документации](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element)

> Если присутствует *src* атрибут, элемент должен быть пустым, либо содержать только [документацию](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts), которая должна удовлетворять [ограничениям на внутренности тега script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements).

Answer (score 3):

Должно быть

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>...и далее код скрипта
```